# Movie that involves half a dozen people from the deep web gathered in a warehouse to see a live killing

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie that starts with this woman waiting to be picked up by a blacked out van. She gets thoroughly searched, she is not packing or wired. She is cheeky and says, I'm on my rags, wanna check?

Then they drive to this abandoned warehouse to where another few deep web users are waiting also. They are all high in the deep web world and have arrogant attitudes so it takes a while for them to warm up to each other, a little bit.

The main reason they are there is to see a young woman be killed. 
The original woman's agenda is to figure out who uploaded the video of her daughter being raped/sodomised/killed, and kill that person. She wanders off away from the others and fishes out a small handgun from her...you know, and goes back and shoots the man she believes responsible.

She gets restrained by the remaining deep webbers and tied up and left while the others go exploring, despite being told to stay put.

The man who organised the 'get together' has a zombified sister who he plans to let slaughter them to be sent to god for their wicked ways.

Things go bad, as they do in movies (lol), and the original woman ends up getting shot and is left to die. The 'organiser' of the gathering has a meek brother who saves the woman's life by injecting her with the same 'zombie' stuff that turned the sister into a zombie.

She ends up 'turning and kills the organiser and the 'real bloke who actually did her daughter wrong.

I saw in in the last ten years. The main lady the story follows has slightly darker skin, almost Latino looking gal. pretty. dark hair just past her shoulders I think. the guy she shoots accidentally is tall and well overweight.

Comment: That's a rather detailed story description. If you remember the plot so well, do you also remember how the characters and scenes looked and can provide some visual descriptions, too? And any other information that may be helpful, like when you watched it, how old the movie was, or from which country it possibly was? Anything else?

Comment: Kindly merge both of you account, so that you can easily eidt your question itself. Refer [this link](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for merging process.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like "[The Death Factory Bloodletting (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1155637/?ref_=nv_sr_1)"

> "Ana Romero has lost all hope. Her daughter was tragically murdered and shes obsessed with finding the person responsible. When a video of her daughters death surfaces on the internet, she tracks it to an underground website know only as the "GOREHOUSE". She poses as an online trader of illegal video material in hopes of finding her daughters killer. Her quest takes her into the bowels of humanity and immerses her in a dark and twisted world of degradation and pain. Her only mission, to find her daughters killer and bring him to justice! She joins a group of online deviants who are invited to an abandoned factory to witness a "Bloodletting", an event displaying the torture and murder of an innocent person. Once inside, they soon realize that they have been lured into a trap by a self-righteous madman, who uses the factory and its bloodthirsty inhabitant as his own personal version of Hell."

Preview: